# Generate table relationship diagram from existing schema (For Sqlite Databse)

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database schema... Is there any tool available that would produce a diagram showing existing tables and their relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac OS X there is [SQLEditor](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/)

On several platforms, [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_datamodeler/modeler_overview.html) Enterprise will do the job

[yEd Graph Editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) can be used to make ER diagrams, but I don't think it will import the schema.

Comment: thanks for SQLEditor tip, it really worked great1